# Is the water that goes a bit inside the (male) private part during istinja and comes out considered pure?

Tags: practical-islam, sunni, taharah

If water goes inside the (male) private part a little bit (but not too deep inside) while you are doing istinja, and you are confirmed that it went inside, and then it came out, is that water considered pure? And is wudu invalidated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alhamdulillah I asked this question on IslamQA and got an answer.

My question was:

> If water goes inside the (male) private part a little bit (but not too deep inside not even that deep so that reaches the end of the circumcised part, just a bit inside which can be seen if the channel of private part is opened) while you are doing istinja, and you are confirmed that it went inside, and then it came out, is that water considered pure? And is wudu invalidated by it coming out? Please mention if there is any difference of opinion. For me when I do istinja a tiny amount of water sometimes goes inside and then comes out, and then I do istinja again and again and it is kind of a endless process.

They answered (There is no editing, I just copied and pasted) :

> Praise be to Allah.
>
> Whoever puts something into his urethra, water, oil or otehr than that, and then it comes out, it is najis and invalidates the wudu. However, if it just onto the opening of the penis and doesn'y actually go inside, then this has no effect.
>
> What you have mentioned seems to be no more than waswas, as it is very difficult for water to actually go inside the penis unless one does that intentionally, which requires exertion and effort.
>
> If we assumed that actually happened, then you simply relieve yourself, then wash yourself (istinja) by washing the head of the penis without opening it to check; you are not required to do more than that, otherwise you will open the door of waswas upon yourself.
>
> And Allah knows best.

For now I can't provide the source as probably this answer is not made public. But Inshaallah I will give the source as soon as it is made public.